# Alternate different models in Pipeline for GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, cross-validation, grid-search

I want to build a Pipeline in sklearn and test different models using GridSearchCV.

Just an example (please do not pay attention on what particular models are chosen):

```
reg = LogisticRegression()

proj1 = PCA(n_components=2)
proj2 = MDS()
proj3 = TSNE()

pipe = [('proj', proj1), ('reg' , reg)]

pipe = Pipeline(pipe)

param_grid = {
    'reg__c': [0.01, 0.1, 1],
}

clf = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid = param_grid)
```

Here if I want to try different models for dimensionality reduction, I need to code different pipelines and compare them manually. Is there an easy way to do it?

One solution I came up with is define my own class derived from base estimator:

```
class Projection(BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, est_name):
        if est_name == "MDS":
            self.model = MDS()
        ...
    ...
    def fit_transform(self, X):
        return self.model.fit_transform(X)
```

I think it will work, I just create a Projection object and pass it to Pipeline, using names of the estimators as parameters for it.

But to me this way is a bit chaotic and not scalable: it makes me to define new class each time I want to compare different models. Also to continue this solution, one could implement a class that does the same job, but with arbitrary set of models. It seems overcomplicated to me.

What is the most natural and pythonic way to compare different models?

Comment: You can directly use estimators as params.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Lets assume you want to use PCA and TruncatedSVD as your dimesionality reduction step.

```
pca = decomposition.PCA()
svd = decomposition.TruncatedSVD()
svm = SVC()
n_components = [20, 40, 64]
```

You can do this:

```
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('reduction', pca), ('svm', svm)])

# Change params_grid -> Instead of dict, make it a list of dict
# In the first element, pass parameters related to pca, and in second related to svd

params_grid = [{
'svm__C': [1, 10, 100, 1000],
'svm__kernel': ['linear', 'rbf'],
'svm__gamma': [0.001, 0.0001],
'reduction':pca,
'reduction__n_components': n_components,
},
{
'svm__C': [1, 10, 100, 1000],
'svm__kernel': ['linear', 'rbf'],
'svm__gamma': [0.001, 0.0001],
'reduction':svd,
'reduction__n_components': n_components,
'reduction__algorithm':['randomized']
}]
```

and now just pass the pipeline object to gridsearchCV

```
grd = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid = params_grid)
```

Calling `grd.fit()` will search the parameters over both the elements of the params_grid list, using all values from `one` at a time.

Please look at my other answer for more details: ["Parallel" pipeline to get best model using gridsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42266737/parallel-pipeline-to-get-best-model-using-gridsearch/42271829#42271829)

Comment: Did I understood correctly that one also needs to include 'reduction': algo_name into each of two elements of param_grid? Otherwise svd is not used in training classifers (if I understood your other answer, which worked for me, correctly).

Comment: @sooobus Aah yes, it was a mistake from my part. Corrected now. Thanks.

Comment: @VivekKumar Excellent answer! FYI, in scikit-learn 0.23 (and possibly in earlier versions), single values in a parameter grid need to be wrapped in a list with one element, otherwise it will error. Thus, you have to use 'reduction':[pca] and 'reduction':[svd] in order for it to work.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative solution that does not require to prefix the estimators names in the parameter grid is the following:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# the models that you want to compare
models = {
    'RandomForestClassifier': RandomForestClassifier(),
    'KNeighboursClassifier': KNeighborsClassifier(),
    'LogisticRegression': LogisticRegression()
}

# the optimisation parameters for each of the above models
params = {
    'RandomForestClassifier':{ 
            "n_estimators"      : [100, 200, 500, 1000],
            "max_features"      : ["auto", "sqrt", "log2"],
            "bootstrap": [True],
            "criterion": ['gini', 'entropy'],
            "oob_score": [True, False]
            },
    'KNeighboursClassifier': {
        'n_neighbors': np.arange(3, 15),
        'weights': ['uniform', 'distance'],
        'algorithm': ['ball_tree', 'kd_tree', 'brute']
        },
    'LogisticRegression': {
        'solver': ['newton-cg', 'sag', 'lbfgs'],
        'multi_class': ['ovr', 'multinomial']
        }  
}
```

and you can define:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

def fit(train_features, train_actuals):
        """
        fits the list of models to the training data, thereby obtaining in each 
        case an evaluation score after GridSearchCV cross-validation
        """
        for name in models.keys():
            est = models[name]
            est_params = params[name]
            gscv = GridSearchCV(estimator=est, param_grid=est_params, cv=5)
            gscv.fit(train_features, train_actuals)
            print("best parameters are: {}".format(gscv.best_estimator_))
```

basically running through the different models, each model referring to its own set of optimisation parameters through a dictionary. Of course do not forget to pass the models and the parameters dictionary to the `fit` function, in case you do not have them as global variables. Have a look [at this GitHub project](https://github.com/gennaro-tedesco/PyScience/blob/master/src/bestclassifier.py) for a more complete overview.

Comment: gscv.fit(train_actuals, train_features) <-- wrong way round I think

Comment: Once i loop through all my models to find best hyperparamaters using gridsearch do i use the model which gave highest "best score value"? e.g. if after doing the above i found that random forest best score= 0.8 and logsiticregression best score= 0.9  would take logistic regression?

Comment: In principle yes, you would take that one model and train it on the entire data set. Notice  that however cross-validation scores are only an indication of the error that one can encounter against unknown test data.

Comment: I think it is not a complete answer since it does not show how to nest the other steps of the pipeline. I have tested it a little bit, but could not find out with your syntax.